# React Native number input mask with always two decimals

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

I am struggling by getting a input mask to work properly. I would like the input to behave like following:

- One inserts 100 then it shows 1.00
- One inserts 30000 then it shows 300.00
- One inserts 4390132 then it shows 43901.32

In the end, I would like that it somehow always has two decimal points no matter the amount of digits

I tried this lib https://github.com/benhurott/react-native-masked-text

But I could only get it to work with limited amount of digits. Would anyone have a suggestion to proceed?

Comment: You could just use `num.slice(0,-2) + '.' + num.slice(-2)`

Comment: @MaheerAli - what happens when there's only 1 digit? or when additional math needs to be performed on the resulting value? This will output a string so more than likely to introduce problems

Comment: @ThatCoderGuy You are correct. Its not best possible solution. Your solution is godd +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some simple maths, you should be able to achieve this.

Firstly divide the number by 100, and then having it cast to a Number you can invoke the toFixed() method, specifying 2 decimal places. Like so:

`Number((num / 100).toFixed(2));`